# How do I install vcpkg with pwsh?

Tags: dockerfile, vcpkg, powershell-core

I am trying to install `vcpkg` but I fail to understand my error. I did follow instructions from [here](https://vcpkg.io/en/getting-started.html).

Here is the minimal steps to reproduce the issue:

```
> docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/7 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0
 ---> 43067ec72d68
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR C:/dev/
 ---> Running in 44765abf2793
Removing intermediate container 44765abf2793
 ---> 863d49ebd1c4
Step 3/7 : ARG VCPKG_VERSION=2023.07.21
 ---> Running in 2c95eca3b986
Removing intermediate container 2c95eca3b986
 ---> 1b6f0b11bef4
Step 4/7 : ADD https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/archive/refs/tags/$VCPKG_VERSION.zip C:\TEMP\vcpkg.zip
Downloading  7.571MB

 ---> c957800f783c
Step 5/7 : RUN tar -xf C:\TEMP\vcpkg.zip     && ren vcpkg-%VCPKG_VERSION% vcpkg     && del /f /q c:\TEMP\*.*;
 ---> Running in e2d020f011a6
Removing intermediate container e2d020f011a6
 ---> d5511b253da3
Step 6/7 : SHELL ["pwsh", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
 ---> Running in 2c4d887da6a1
Removing intermediate container 2c4d887da6a1
 ---> 14b149981886
Step 7/7 : RUN .\vcpkg\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat -disableMetrics;
 ---> Running in 31e9ab80d53d
'powershell.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What should I do about this `pwsh.exe` vs `powershell.exe` ?

Where:

```
> cat Dockerfile
# escape=`
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0

WORKDIR C:/dev/

ARG VCPKG_VERSION=2023.07.21
ADD https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/archive/refs/tags/$VCPKG_VERSION.zip C:\TEMP\vcpkg.zip

RUN tar -xf C:\TEMP\vcpkg.zip `
    && ren vcpkg-%VCPKG_VERSION% vcpkg `
    && del /f /q c:\TEMP\*.*;

SHELL ["pwsh", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

RUN .\vcpkg\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat -disableMetrics;
```

For reference:

```
> docker run --rm mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 pwsh --version
PowerShell 7.3.10
```

while:

```
> docker run --rm mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 powershell --version
docker: Error response from daemon: container 615360a3654bbe128045fa96770d163dc6c9079b9e86e6d42357eb9e6ee6d10e encountered an error during hcs::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF606A8A1DB: (caller: 00007FF606A3E19A) Exception(1) tid(390) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess]
 Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000].
```

And batch file is:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/bootstrap-vcpkg.bat

Answer (score 0):

Seems overly complex to do a simple task. Here is what I got when not changing the default `SHELL`:

```
# escape=`
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0

# Cannot update path, need hackish solution:
# https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docker/issues/236
ENV PATH="C:\Windows\system32;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\powershell;C:\Program Files\MinGit\cmd;C:\dev\vcpkg"

ARG VCPKG_VERSION=2023.07.21
# https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/2023.07.21/scripts/bootstrap.ps1
# Naming convention taken from recent https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/2023.11.20/scripts/bootstrap.ps1
ARG VCPKG_TOOL_RELEASE_TAG=2023-07-19

WORKDIR C:/dev/

RUN `
    pwsh -command "Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile C:\dev\vcpkg.zip https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/archive/refs/tags/%VCPKG_VERSION%.zip" `
    # Extract:
    && tar -xf C:\dev\vcpkg.zip `
    && del /q c:\dev\vcpkg.zip `
    # Remove version from folder name:
    && ren vcpkg-%VCPKG_VERSION% vcpkg `
    # Cannot use the default `curl` does not seems to download anything (302 issue?)
    # && curl -o vcpkg/vcpkg.exe https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg-tool/releases/download/%VCPKG_TOOL_RELEASE_TAG%/vcpkg.exe
    # Same goes for the tool `tls12-download.exe` seems to be missing a dll ?
    # Use Invoke-WebRequest  instead:
    && pwsh -command "Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile vcpkg/vcpkg.exe https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg-tool/releases/download/%VCPKG_TOOL_RELEASE_TAG%/vcpkg.exe";
```

Quick check:

```
> docker build -t vcpkg-test .
> docker run --rm vcpkg-test vcpkg --version
vcpkg package management program version 2023-07-19-814b7ec837b59f1c8778f72351c1dd7605983cd2

See LICENSE.txt for license information.
```

---

Posted as issue:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/35422